# Landing Page - Overlapping of divisions in mobile. Fine in Web

Tags: html

Am beginner in coding. I have designed a landing page. The landing page looks fine in website but divisions are overlapping in mobile. Kindly check and advice how to resolve this problem?

[Landing Page Link](https://www.ayoga.in/construction-project-management-software)

Thanks in advance

Comment: so whats the relation of your issue to php?

Comment: Sorry removed that now

Answer (score 0):

You have an inline `height` of `3px` on your `ul id="grids"`.

Remove that or set it to `auto` and its should stack properly.

Comment: Hi Conor , What should i do for this page? http://www.ayoga.in/construction-project-management-software-mobile.  This is working fine for mobile. But for web at a resolution of  1920*1080 , the pictures are not stacked properly

Answer (score 0):

you are using bootstrap the columns must wrap with row class and row should be warped in container or container-fluid classses

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

OR

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have implemented below solution, it worked well

Answer (score 0):

change bootstrap nav use this one [http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/ ] it's batter to responsive and mobile devices .